# Need some help on shell scipt (using grep command)

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a log file and I am trying to write a shell script to find multiple strings in a file on multiple lines.

For example if I see the phrases "class=com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse" and "status:OK" together in the logs, I should print getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL else getAudioLanguage FAILED. So my shell script goes like this:

Scriptfile:

```
logfile=$1

if grep "{\"class\":\"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse\"" jags.txt | grep "{\"status\":\"OK\"" | wc -l ; then
    echo "getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL"
fi
if grep "{\"class\":\"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse\"" $logfile | grep -q "GENERAL_ERROR" | wc -l ; then
    echo "getAudioLanguage FAILED"
fi
```

In the logs, I get status as GENERAL_ERROR, so it should print FAILED, but the output shows as getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL ..

Any help regarding this?

Logfile:

```
160125-11:11:28.442500 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] ======= Message is onRPCCall ======>
160125-11:11:28.442614 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] Entering onRPCCallEvent for request ---> getAudioLanguage
160125-11:11:28.442845 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] Received json request = {"event":1,"handler":1,"name":"onRPCCall","params":{"callGUID":"d75a5bab-6b29-4ab4-9f7e-3cf32d4a05b1","callParams":[{"getAudioLanguage":{}}],"class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XRERPCCallInfo","destinationSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d","method":"getAudioLanguage","sourceSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"},"phase":"STANDARD","source":1}

160125-11:11:28.442920 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] GetCurrentAudioLanguage : Entered
160125-11:11:28.442968 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] pMainPlayer is NULL.
160125-11:11:28.443012 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] getAudioLanguage: Get Audio Language returned ��v`>       T�=     T0~�t
160125-11:11:28.443676 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] ====== Response sending is {"appId":1,"command":"CALL","commandIndex":5,"method":"generateAppEvent","params":[{"class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XREOutgoingEvent","name":"onRPCReturn","params":{"callGUID":"d75a5bab-6b29-4ab4-9f7e-3cf32d4a05b1","class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XRERPCReturnInfo","destinationSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d","method":"getAudioLanguage","returnVal":{"class":"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse","status":"GENERAL_ERROR","statusMessage":"Getting Current Audio Language was unsuccessful."},"sourceSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"}},"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"],"targetId":1,"targetPath":"","timestamp":0}
```

Comment: start with `help if`. `grep -q` sets exit status to 0, which is available in variable `#?` if match is found. Check against that (`help test`). Hint `if [ #? -eq 0 ]`

Comment: That's `$?`, not `#?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than multiple `grep` you can use a single `awk` to do this:

```
awk '/{"class":"com\.comcast\.parker\.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse"/{
   exit ($0 !~ /"status":"GENERAL_ERROR"/)}' file && echo "getAudioLanguage FAILED"

awk '/{"class":"com\.comcast\.parker\.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse"/{
   exit ($0 !~ /"status":"OK"/)}' file && echo "getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL"
```

Comment: Not a bad idea but I don't think there's anything wrong with using `if` here, rather than `&&`.

Comment: Right using `if` isn't any issue at all. I suggested `awk` to avoid multiple `grep`

Comment: Makes sense. It's a shame that in order to indicate a successful match it is necessary to exit with a status equal to _not a match_ - I wonder if there's a nicer way to express this?

Comment: Yes a successful match will return `1` but `exit 1` means failure in shell, that's why we need to take inverse of the match. But yes it indeed looks somewhat confusing :)

Comment: Thanks Done..Hope it helps others to know the awkwardly power of 'Awk' :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your search patterns are written correctly, then you could use something like this:

```
if grep pattern_one file | grep -q pattern_two; then
    echo "getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL"
fi
```

This filters the output on the first pattern and uses `grep -q`, whose exit status indicates whether the second pattern also matches.

That said, it kinda looks like you're attempting to parse JSON. It'd be better to use something like `jq` for this if possible.